# pythonbrew with mod_wsgi

Tags: pythonbrew

pythonbrew isn't getting picked up by by mod_wsgi file, config follows:

```
import os
import sys
import site

site.addsitedir('/home/bharal/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.append ('/home/bharal/public_html/dumpstown')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'dumpstown.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

and the pythonbrew version of python i want to use is situated here:

> /home/bharal/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages

and my pythonbrew install is here:

> /home/bharal/.pythonbrew/

How do i tell mod_wsgi to use *this* version (2.7.2) and not the  default python version that shipped with ubuntu (2.6)?

When i run my server, i get errors like so:

```
[Wed Jul 04 02:17:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=18694): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/bharal/public_html/dumpstown/dumpstown/apache/dumpstown.wsgi'.
[Wed Jul 04 02:17:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jul 04 02:17:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
[Wed Jul 04 02:17:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self.load_middleware()
[Wed Jul 04 02:17:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
[Wed Jul 04 02:17:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Wed Jul 04 02:17:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
[Wed Jul 04 02:17:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._setup()
[Wed Jul 04 02:17:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
[Wed Jul 04 02:17:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Wed Jul 04 02:17:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __init__
[Wed Jul 04 02:17:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Wed Jul 04 02:17:27 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: Could not import settings 'dumpstown.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named gravatar.templatetags
```

as you can see from the logs, the server is *still* looking at python 2.6!! Why? I've kicked off pythonbrew so when *i* type in `python` i can see the version is 2.7.2, and all the settings and packages i need are importable!

**UPDATE** as indicated in the answer below, the mod_wsgi doesn't *care* which python i *tell* it to use - in fact, i cannot tell it to use any particular python. The only way to do so is to download an uncompiled wsgi file, compile with the particular python version i want, and use the  compiled wsgi.

See my other question [Error: Command failed with rc=65536 python and mod_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11332717/1061426) for some of the steps and links to tutes if you like. In the end i *didn't* compile against 2.7 (my 2.6 was fine and it was too hard to get the pythonbrew compile working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular error has nothing to do with the version of Python used. Use:

sys.path.append ('/home/bharal/public_html')
  sys.path.append ('/home/bharal/public_html/dumpstown')

To get mod_wsgi to use a specific version, compile it from source code against that version or find a binary package for mod_wsgi compiled against the correct version.